# Publish (copy-ish) a console application in visual studio to file system + topshelf cmds

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, console-application, publish, topshelf

I have a console app that I want to be able to publish in a really simple way. I simply want to copy the relevant files into a folder of my choice.

The build in publish function of visual studio is doing all kinds of weird stuff... I don't want or like it.

I simply want the "publish to file system" that you can get when publish an ASP.NET application.

---

As a bonus it would be cool if the publish (script) could run some commands also. My console app is made with topshelf so reinstalling and starting the service on publish would be real neat.

Something like:

1. publish folder/myfile.exe uninstall
2. ... copy files to publish folder
3. publish folder/myfile.exe install start

Comment: I would think you could accomplish this easily with a post-build script

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm searching for. I want to right click on my console project, select Publish and have it built and copied to one of my internal servers. I dont want to open /bin and do a copy & paste. A post build script could do exactly this but thats not what I want.